# Golang 1.18 - Exclude package for specific platform

Tags: go, build, constraints

I spent the whole day trying to apply a build constraint in my code:
I have an agent that is designed to work on Windows and Linux, however, I have to interact with the Windows registry (which obviously doesn't have any equivalent on Linux).

My package imports

> "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"

The project builds on Windows but not on Linux.
I then learnt about build constraints: //go:build windows (or !linux)
I initially started with // +build windows but I saw that it's for older Go versions.

Here is the header of my package file:

```
//go:build windows

package utils

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)
...
```

I use VSCode both on Windows and Linux, I can also see a reference to in my go.mod file.
Any help with this please?

When I run the code above, I still get the following on Linux:

> build golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry: cannot load
> golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry: no Go source files (exit status 1)

**Edit:** I use the default VSCode tools to compile and run my project, however I have tried: go build . and I still get the same error.
Also, the _windows.go and _linux.go suffixes are not appropriate as the agent would be fore Mac in the future.

Comment: That package is for Windows only. So if you can't build and run it on Linux, that means the opposite: build constraints does work. You can't use that package on linux. If your app must run both on Windows and linux, you also have to use platform dependent code (build constraints) to do something else when on Linux.

Comment: Thanks both. @icza, that makes sense, is there any way I could have a constraint to tell the compiler "ignore this package only if building on Linux?" instead of failing?

Comment: @Dlionis That package is ignored, but your code is referring to it. That's why your code fails. You have to add build constraint to your package that uses it, to also only target / compile on windows. You must have different files for linux, that may do no-op or what makes sense for you when targeting linux.

Comment: Hmmm okay thank you. Is it worth having two separate projects? Or are there any other build constraints you would recommend to keep the same code for all platforms by targeting compilation on Windows?

Comment: This depends on what your app does. But supporting multiple platforms with different code via build constraints is completely normal and doesn't warrant a new project.

Comment: If it's just Windows vs. Linux you can use the `_windows.go` and `_linux.go` source file name suffixes instead of the build tag meta comment. Not sure if those have fallen out of favor, but they do work and make it easier to see what platform the file is for.

Comment: I reopened because your edit clarifies that the previous linked solution doesn't apply, but it's still unclear how you are getting the issue. In order to receive a proper answer, you should provide more details about your file names, where this `utils` package is used, what you are building with `go build` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't write the entire thing in the comments but let me know if this small sample helps you:

utils_darwin.go:

```
package utils

import "fmt"

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test from mac")
}
```

utils_linux.go

```
package utils

import "fmt"

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test from linux")
}
```

utils_windows.go

```
package utils

import "fmt"

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test from windows")
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import "github.com/ninadingole/go-dev-stuff/platform/utils"

func main() {
    utils.Test()
}
```

When I compile the binary on mac and run it like:

```
GOOS=darwin go build -o prog ./platform

./prog

Test from mac
```

I tried to build the binary in docker for linux and got the below output

```
Test from linux
```

Let me know if this works for you otherwise I will delete the answer :D

Comment: Neenad I tried to build that way after adding _windows.go as a suffix to the filename:
env GOOS=linux go build


And got the following result:
build xxx/xxx/detection/windows/utils: cannot load xxx/xxx/detection/windows/utils: no Go source files

Comment: I don't know why you are getting the error. It is very hard to understand the problem without proper code the implementation and the caller of the code. I would say you can create a small git project or a `gist` with all the files and share them here.

Comment: I tested locally and it works, I didn't even need the /go:build directive, just renaming the file with a suffix was enough. Thank you very much Neenad!